# String of list or strings to a tuple

Tags: python, string, iterable

I've got a class attribute which can be either a string or a list of strings. I want to convert it into a tuple such that a list converts normally, but a single string becomes a single-item tuple:

`[str, str] --> (str, str)`

`str        --> (str, )`

Unfortunately `tuple('sting')` returns `('s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g')` which is not what I expect. Is it possible to do it without type checking?

Comment: You're asking to do something based on the type of the value. By definition, this requires some form of type checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type checking would be a great way to achieve this. How would you otherwise decide if the input was a list or a string?.

You could make a function which tests if the input is a list or a string and returns appropriately and handles the rest as you see fit. Something along the lines of

```
>>> def convert_to_tuple(elem):
        if isinstance(elem, list):
            return tuple(elem)
        elif isinstance(elem, basestring):
            return (elem,)
        else:
            # Do Something
            pass


>>> convert_to_tuple('abc')
('abc',)
>>> convert_to_tuple(['abc', 'def'])
('abc', 'def')
```

You could only check for strings too, (Assuming Python 2.x, replace `basestring` with `str` in Py3)

```
>>> def convert_to_tuple(elem):
        if isinstance(elem, basestring):
            return (elem,)
        else:
            return tuple(elem)


>>> convert_to_tuple('abc')
('abc',)
>>> convert_to_tuple(('abc', 'def'))
('abc', 'def')
>>> convert_to_tuple(['abc', 'def'])
('abc', 'def')
```

Converting the function to a one liner is possible too.

```
>>> def convert_to_tuple(elem):
        return (elem,) if isinstance(elem, basestring) else tuple(elem)
```

Comment: They asked for a method without type checking so I'm assuming they already know how to do this?

Comment: AFAIK Type Checking would be the best way to achieve this. :)

Comment: Thank you. I just wondered if there is another way, since type checking is (correctly) considered unelegant.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
>>> s = 'str'
>>> print (s,)
('str',)
```

There's no need to call [`tuple()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) when dealing with strings to achieve what you're trying.

If you need one method to help both types, then you can't avoid type checking:

```
def tuplising(typ):
    return tuple(typ) if isinstance(typ, list) else (typ,)
```

Comment: Yes, but applying your proposition to a list will return `(['abc', 'cde'], )` where I need `('abc', 'cde').